# ByRef Error when passing an integer into a subroutine in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use some code I found elsewhere on StackOverflow called `Quicksort` which is a means of sorting the elements of an array.

I am struggling with `ByRef` errors which appear to occur as I pass integer values to the `Quicksort` subroutine.

My code is currently:

(in the main subroutine)

```
  ReDim Preserve arrDataToSort(1 To 3, 2 To intCol - 1)
  Call subQuickSort(arrDataToSort, 2)
```

(in a separate module)

```
  Public Sub subQuickSort(ByRef var1 As Variant, _
                        ByVal intRowtoSort As Integer)
  end sub
```

At the moment I get an error on the `ByVal intRowtoSort As Integer` line saying `Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch`

Is anyone able to shed any light on this?  If I delete the second argument (intRowtoSort) the error doesn't occur

******EDIT******

Following some of the comments, here is the full section of the code

```
ReDim arrDataToSort(1 To 3, 2 To countRows) As Variant 'declare an array to be used to sort the data - don't know dimensions yet, so make too big...
'done the above as transpose as can only ReDim second dimension of an array...
Dim intCol As Integer: intCol = 2 'defines the next blank col in arrDataToSort

For i = 2 To 1000 'countRows        
    If formulaarray1(i, uniqueCOL) = 1 Then  'i.e. unique patient ID
        arrDataToSort(1, intCol) = Sheets(sheet_DATA).Cells(i, IDCOL).Value
        arrDataToSort(2, intCol) = Sheets(sheet_DATA).Cells(i, FreqCOL).Value
        arrDataToSort(3, intCol) = Sheets(sheet_DATA).Cells(i, FreqCOL2).Value
        intCol = intCol + 1 'increment to identify next blank row
    End If

Next i

ReDim Preserve arrDataToSort(1 To 3, 2 To intCol - 1) 'respecify the size of the array whilst preserving the data

'attempt to sort the data by the UniqueFreqCOL values using QuickSort subroutine
Call subQuickSort(arrDataToSort,2)
```

Additional Comments:

- I have also managed to get the same ByRef error with the second argument for the function removed, so it does seem the problem is with my array
- I am using `ReDim` without a prior `Dim` as this lets me use a variable to specify the dimensions of the array - I now understand I don't need to do this from the comments made :)

**Further Edits**
 The quicksort code (with my very minor edits) is

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub subQuickSort(ByRef var1 As Variant)

Dim intRowtoSort As Integer: intRowtoSort = 2

Dim varPivot As Variant
Dim lngLow As Long, lngHigh As Long, lngLowStart As Long, lngHighStart As Long

lngLowStart = LBound(var1, 2)
lngHighStart = UBound(var1, 2)
lngLow = lngLowStart
lngHigh = lngHighStart

varPivot = var1(intRowtoSort, (lngLowStart + lngHighStart) \ 2)

While (lngLow <= lngHigh)
    While (var1(intRowtoSort, lngLow) < varPivot And lngLow < lngHighStart)
        lngLow = lngLow + 1
    Wend

    While (varPivot < var1(intRowtoSort, lngHigh) And lngHigh > lngLowStart)
        lngHigh = lngHigh - 1
    Wend

    If (lngLow <= lngHigh) Then
        subSwap var1, lngLow, lngHigh
        lngLow = lngLow + 1
        lngHigh = lngHigh - 1
    End If
Wend

If (lngLowStart < lngHigh) Then
    subQuickSort var1, lngLowStart, lngHigh    (***)
End If
If (lngLow < lngHighStart) Then
    subQuickSort var1, lngLow, lngHighStart
End If

End Sub

Private Sub subSwap(var As Variant, intRowtoSort As Integer, lngItem1 As Long, lngItem2 As Long)
Dim varTemp As Variant
varTemp = var(intRowtoSort, lngItem1)
var(intRowtoSort, lngItem1) = var(intRowtoSort, lngItem2)
var(intRowtoSort, lngItem2) = varTemp
End Sub
```

The only other thing to potentially note is that when I get the eror box pop up, the yellow arrow is by the line `public sortQuickSort` but also `lngLow` is highlighted in the line above with (***)

Comment: Take a look here at the MS explanation for the error - seems like your problem is on the `type` used for `arrDataToSort` when initially declared?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/138535

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have been looking through this help file already, but struggling to implement a change that works.  The first (and only prior) declaration of `arrDatatoSort` is `ReDim arrDataToSort(1 To 3, 2 To countRows) As Variant`

Comment: You can't `ReDim` something that hasn't already been `Dim`'d, I suggest you check again?  Maybe post the whole of the main subroutine so there's more to go on

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted (and you can't get a `ByRef` error on a variable passed `ByVal`). Can you post the full code?

Comment: @Dave Yes you can - the first declaration of an array can be a `ReDim` statement.

Comment: Can you post the subQuickSort code too please, since I assume it's recursive?

Comment: FYI, if you use `Dim arrDataToSort() As Variant` then you can later `ReDim` using a variable as you do currently.

Comment: You should be getting an error about the wrong number of arguments really. Your routine is trying to call itself passing **three** arguments, when it's only declared with one.

Comment: Thanks @Rory, your comments have led me to rectify the problem - i was trying a number of options as i edited the code above and i think there must have been a couple of inconsistencies.  You made me realise that the array wasn't declared in the same way in the `subswap` subroutine and VBA was indirectly complaining about that